# NoErrorObjectAvailable Script error Salesforce LWC when updating LWC data table with changed picklist value

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lightning-datatable, custom

I have implemented Custom type (custom component and custom data table) to show picklist values in LWC datatable. I have an event fired from this custom component and handling this event in my component.
when pick list value is changed I want to update draft values to show 'save and cancel' and update table data. when trying to updated table data, I am receiving this error "[NoErrorObjectAvailable] Script error". Any pointers would help.

I have used below link for creating this componenet

https://live.playg.app/play/picklist-in-lightning-datatable

Here is my code:

dataTablepicklist.html

```
<template>
<div class="picklist-container">
<lightning-combobox name="picklist" label={label} value={value} placeholder={placeholder} options={options}
onchange={handleChange}></lightning-combobox>
```

datatablePicklist.js

```
import { LightningElement,api } from 'lwc';

export default class DatatablePicklist extends LightningElement {

    @api label;
    @api placeholder;
    @api options;
    @api value;
    @api context;

    handleChange(event) {
        //show the selected value on UI
        this.value = event.detail.value;

        //fire event to send context and selected value to the data table
        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('picklistchanged', {
            composed: true,
            bubbles: true,
            detail: {
                picklistData: {context: this.context,value: this.value, placeholder: this.placeholder}
            }
        }
        ));
    }

}
```

picklist-template.html

```
<template>
    <c-datatable-picklist label={typeAttributes.label} value={typeAttributes.value}
    placeholder={typeAttributes.placeholder} options={typeAttributes.options} context={typeAttributes.context}>
</c-datatable-picklist>  
</template>
```

customDataTable.js

```
import LightningDatatable from 'lightning/datatable';
import DatatablePicklistTemplate from './picklist-template.html';
import {
    loadStyle
} from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import CustomDataTableResource from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/CustomDataTable';

export default class CustomDataTable extends LightningDatatable {
    static customTypes = {
        picklist: {
            template: DatatablePicklistTemplate,
            typeAttributes: ['label', 'placeholder', 'options', 'value', 'context'],
        },

    };

    constructor() {
        super();
        Promise.all([
            loadStyle(this, CustomDataTableResource),
        ]).then(() => {})
    }

}
```

### Custom component to show the custom datable with picklist

HTML file

```
    <template>
        <c-custom-data-table
                        key-field="id"
                        data={productData}
                        columns={columns}
                        hide-checkbox-column="true"
                        show-row-number-column="true"
                        min-column-width="75"
                        draft-values={draftValues}
                        oncellchange={handleCellChange}
                        onpicklistchanged={picklistChanged}
                        onrowaction={handleRowAction}
                         >
        </c-custom-data-table>
           
</template>
```

### JS file-- **I am getting error in **updateDataValues** method inside the for loop where I am trying to update loop variable with new picklist value**

```
import { LightningElement,api,track } from 'lwc';
import createLineItems from '@salesforce/apex/AddProductsController.createLineItems';

const AUDIENCEOPTIONS = [
  {value: 'Parents', label: 'Parents'},
  {value: 'Kids', label: 'Kids'},
  {value: 'Teens', label: 'Teens'} 
];
const COLS = [
    {label: 'Product', fieldName: 'name',wrapText: true},
    {label:'Quantity',fieldName:'Quantity',editable: true},
    {label: 'Sales Metric', fieldName: 'salesMetric', type: 'picklist',wrapText: true,typeAttributes: {
      placeholder: 'Choose a value', options: [
        { label: 'CPA', value: 'CPA' },
        { label: 'CPC', value: 'CPC' },
        { label: 'CPCV', value: 'CPCV' },
        { label: 'CPI', value: 'CPI' },
        { label: 'CPM', value: 'CPM' },
        { label: 'CPVI', value: 'CPVI' },
        { label: 'Flat Rate', value: 'Flat Rate' },
        { label: 'CPE', value: 'CPE' },
      ]
      , value: { fieldName: 'salesMetric' } // default value for picklist
      , context: { fieldName: 'id' }
    // binding account Id with context variable to be returned back
  }},
    {label:'Sales Price',fieldName:'UnitPrice',editable: true,required:true},
   // {label:'Target Audience',fieldName: 'targetAudience',editable:true},
    {
      label:'Target Audience', fieldName: 'targetAudience', type: 'picklist',wrapText: true,typeAttributes: {
          placeholder: 'Choose Target Audience', options: [
            { label: 'Parents', value: 'Parents' },
            { label: 'Kids', value: 'Kids' },
            { label: 'Teens', value: 'Teens' }
          ] // list of all picklist options
          , value: { fieldName: 'targetAudience' } // default value for picklist
          , context: { fieldName: 'id' }
        // binding account Id with context variable to be returned back
      }
  },
    {label:'Target Age',fieldName: 'targetAge',type: 'picklist',wrapText: true,typeAttributes: {
      placeholder: 'Choose target Age', options:[ { label: '0-3', value: '0-3' },
      { label: '4-6', value: '4-6' },
      { label: '7-9', value: '7-9' },
      { label: '10-12', value: '10-12' },
      { label: '13-16', value: '13-16' },
      { label: 'NA', value: 'NA' },
      ] // list of all picklist options
      , value: { fieldName: 'targetAge'} // default value for picklist
      , context: { fieldName: 'id' }
    // binding account Id with context variable to be returned back
  }},
    {label:'Target Gender',fieldName:'targetGender',type: 'picklist',wrapText: true,typeAttributes: {
      placeholder: 'Choose Target Gender', options:[ { label: 'Boys', value: 'Boys' },
      { label: 'Girls', value: 'Girls' },
      { label: 'Boys & Girls', value: 'Boys & Girls' },
      ] // list of all picklist options
      , value: { fieldName: 'targetGender'} // default value for picklist
      , context: { fieldName: 'id' }
      , label:{fieldName:'label'}
    }
  },
    {label:'Device Type',fieldName:'deviceType'},
    {label:'KSV Price Plan',fieldName:'ksvPricePlan'},
    {label:'Start Date',fieldName: 'startDate',editable: true,type:'date',wrapText: true},
    {label:'End Date',fieldName: 'endDate',editable: true,type:'date',wrapText: true},
    {label:'Format',fieldName:'format'},
    {label:'Media Type',fieldName:'mediaType'},
    {label:'Delivery Type',fieldName:'deliveryType'},
    {
      type: 'button-icon',
      initialWidth: 75,
      typeAttributes: {
          iconName:'utility:copy',
          title: 'Copy'
      }
  },
    //{label:'Frequency Cap',fieldName:'FrequencyCap',editable:true},
    //{label:'Frequency Cap Period',fieldName:'FrequencyCapPeriod',editable:true}   
];

export default class EditAndSaveProducts extends LightningElement {

    @api recordId;

    @api productAttibutes;

    @track productData;

    columns = COLS;
    @track draftValues = [];


    
    @api 
    get products(){
        return this.productData;
      }
  
      set products(value){
          console.log(value);
        this.productData=value;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.productData));
      }

    get metricOptions() {
        return [
                 { label: 'CPA', value: 'CPA' },
                 { label: 'CPC', value: 'CPC' },
                 { label: 'CPCV', value: 'CPCV' },
                 { label: 'CPI', value: 'CPI' },
                 { label: 'CPM', value: 'CPM' },
                 { label: 'CPVI', value: 'CPVI' },
                 { label: 'Flat Rate', value: 'Flat Rate' },
                 { label: 'CPE', value: 'CPE' },
               ];
    }

    get deviceOptions(){
        return [
            { label: 'Connected TV', value: 'CConnected TV' },
            { label: 'Desktop', value: 'Desktop' },
            { label: 'Phone', value: 'Phone' },
            { label: 'Tablet', value: 'Tablet' },
          ];
    }

    

     /*handleSave(event){
      console.log('inside save');

 } */

 picklistChanged(event){
   event.stopPropagation(); 
   let dataRecieved = event.detail.picklistData;
   console.log('data Recieved'+ JSON.stringify(dataRecieved));
   if(dataRecieved.placeholder=='Choose Target Audience'){
   var updatedItem = { id: dataRecieved.context, targetAudience: dataRecieved.value};
   }
   else if(dataRecieved.placeholder=='Choose target Age'){
    var updatedItem = { id: dataRecieved.context, targetAge: dataRecieved.value};
    }

    else if(dataRecieved.placeholder=='Choose Target Gender'){
      var updatedItem = { id: dataRecieved.context, targetGender: dataRecieved.value};
      }
   console.log('picklist changed'+JSON.stringify(updatedItem));
   this.updateDraftValues(updatedItem);
   this.updateDataValues(updatedItem);

}


handleRowAction(event){
  console.log('inside row action');
  
}

handleCellChange(event) {
  console.log('inside cell change');
  this.updateDraftValues(event.detail.draftValues[0]);
  //this.updateDataValues(event.detail.draftValues[0])
}

updateDraftValues(updateItem) {
  console.log('inside draft values'+this.draftValues);
  let draftValueChanged = false;
  let copyDraftValues = [...this.draftValues];

  //store changed value to do operations
  //on save. This will enable inline editing &
  //show standard cancel & save button
  copyDraftValues.forEach(item => {
    console.log('inside loop');
      if (item.id === updateItem.id) {
          for (let field in updateItem) {
              item[field] = updateItem[field];
          }
          draftValueChanged = true;
      }
  });

  if (draftValueChanged) {
      this.draftValues = [...copyDraftValues];
  } else {
      this.draftValues = [...copyDraftValues, updateItem];
  }
  console.log('draft values'+ JSON.stringify(this.draftValues));
}

updateDataValues(updateItem) {
  console.log('inside update values'+JSON.stringify(updateItem));
  let copyData = [...this.productData];
  console.log('copydata'+JSON.stringify(copyData))
   copyData.forEach(item => {

      if (item.id === updateItem.id) {
        for (let field in updateItem) {
           console.log('line 257'+ item['Target Audience']);
            console.log('line 258'+updateItem[field]);
              item[field] = updateItem[field];
          } 
       }
  });

  //write changes back to original data
   this.productData = [...copyData];
  //console.log('data'+JSON.stringify(this.productData))
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

After research found that data was in read only mode. Fixed the issue by adding one more line as below in updateDataValues method

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(copydata)
```